# Selection of a Series from pandas dataframe by interpolating column labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains for multiple positions (defined by coordinate `x`) a value for different timesteps. I want to create a `pandas.Series` object that contains the value at a given position `x` for all timesteps (so all index-values of the dataframe). If `x` is not one of the column labels, I want to interpolate between the two nearest `x` values.

An excerpt from the dataframe object (`min(x)=0` and `max(x)=0.28`):

```
          0.000000  0.007962  0.018313  0.031770  0.049263  0.072004
time (s)                                                               
15760800  0.500481  0.500481  0.500481  0.500481  0.500481  0.500481   
15761400  1.396126  0.487198  0.498765  0.501326  0.500234  0.500544   
15762000  1.455313  0.542441  0.489421  0.502851  0.499945  0.500597   
15762600  1.492908  0.592022  0.487835  0.502233  0.500139  0.500527   
15763200  1.521089  0.636743  0.490874  0.500704  0.500485  0.500423   
15763800  1.542632  0.675589  0.496401  0.499065  0.500788  0.500335
```

I can find ways to slice the dataframe by available column labels. But is there an elegant way to do the interpolation?

In the end I want a function that looks something like this: `result = sliceDataframe( dataframe=dfin,x=0.01)`,with result a `pandas.Series` object so I can call it in one line (or maybe two) in another postprocessing script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be best with writing a simple function yourself. Something like:

```
def sliceDataframe(df, x):
    # supposing the column labels are sorted:
    pos = np.searchsorted(df.columns.values, x)

    # select the two neighbouring column labels:
    left = df.columns[pos-1]
    right = df.columns[pos]

    # simple interpolation
    interpolated =  df[left] + (df[right] - df[left])/(right - left) * (x - left)
    interpolated.name = x
    return interpolated
```

Another option is to use the `interpolate` method, but therefore, you should add a column with NaNs with the label you want.
With the function of above:

```
In [105]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,4))

In [106]: df.columns = df.columns.astype(float)

In [107]: df
Out[107]:
          0         1         2         3
0 -0.336453  1.219877 -0.912452 -1.047431
1  0.842774 -0.361236 -0.245771  0.014917
2 -0.974621  1.050503  0.367389  0.789570
3  1.091484  1.352065  1.215290  0.393900
4 -0.100972 -0.250026 -1.135837 -0.339204
5  0.503436 -0.764224 -1.099864  0.962370
6 -0.599090  0.908235 -0.581446  0.662604
7 -2.234131  0.512995 -0.591829 -0.046959

In [108]: sliceDataframe(df, 0.5)
Out[108]:
0    0.441712
1    0.240769
2    0.037941
3    1.221775
4   -0.175499
5   -0.130394
6    0.154572
7   -0.860568
Name: 0.5, dtype: float64
```

With the `interpolate` method:

```
In [109]: df[0.5] = np.NaN

In [110]: df.sort(axis=1).interpolate(axis=1)
Out[110]:
        0.0       0.5       1.0       2.0       3.0
0 -0.336453  0.441712  1.219877 -0.912452 -1.047431
1  0.842774  0.240769 -0.361236 -0.245771  0.014917
2 -0.974621  0.037941  1.050503  0.367389  0.789570
3  1.091484  1.221775  1.352065  1.215290  0.393900
4 -0.100972 -0.175499 -0.250026 -1.135837 -0.339204
5  0.503436 -0.130394 -0.764224 -1.099864  0.962370
6 -0.599090  0.154572  0.908235 -0.581446  0.662604
7 -2.234131 -0.860568  0.512995 -0.591829 -0.046959

In [111]: df.sort(axis=1).interpolate(axis=1)[0.5]
Out[111]:
0    0.441712
1    0.240769
2    0.037941
3    1.221775
4   -0.175499
5   -0.130394
6    0.154572
7   -0.860568
Name: 0.5, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I don't want to adjust the dataframe with a fictive point. Is there a way to use the interpolate option without adding a column? If no, then I think I will go for the first solution.

Comment: No, the pandas interpolation method always fills NaNs in DataFrame. But maybe it would be possible using the underlying scipy interpolation method. But as the interpolation itself is just one line for a simple linear interpolation once you have selected the two neighbouring columns, I don't know it is worth using that.

Comment: implemented the first option works fine and fast enough for post-processing. Thank you